# AngularJS: Resource not sending parameters with undefined vars

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a basic form setup with a controller, and when the user submits the form, this function is ran:

```
$scope.create = function(email, username, password) {
MyService.get({
    action: 'create',
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password
}, function(data) {
    // Success callback
});
};
```

The problem is that if the user submits the form with an empty field, the php receiving this request throws an undefined index error for that field.

Ex: User doesn't fill in email and presses submit. The php throws an error because `$_GET['email']` is an undefined index.

How can I get it so that the resource just sends an empty value if the field is empty? (I'd prefer this to adding `array_key_exists` checks or the likes for everything in the php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign empty strings as fallback values, like this:

```
MyService.get({
    action: 'create',
    email: email || '',
    username: username || '',
    password: password || ''
}), // ..
```

But let me tell you this: relying on client-side validation *only* is *usually* a bad practice. I hope this is some internal project which will never have some evil-doers preying upon the requests led astray. Otherwise you'd better use `isset|empty` in your server code.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. And this is actually just some middleware that's between this server and an api server so I don't have to do anything with jsonp and can edit some stuff before sending it to the api. The api does all the checking.